# How to Upload an Image to Cloudinary with Angular Form and Express Backend(NodeJS)

Tags: angular, express, cloudinary, ngmodel

I am trying to use a NG Model form to upload data to my backend. It works as expected until I try to use an input type file. My goal with this input file type is to upload an image to a Cloudinary storage in my backend. I have read that for an input type file it is better to use (change), so this is what I have done.

```
                <input class="form-control" type="file" (change)="getPokemonImage($event)" #fileUpload >
```

The issue I am currently having with the above is the data displays in my frontend console logs, but it does not return in my backend.

I have made a stackblitz of my code. If anyone could help me configure my data to the backend and succesfully upload to my database/cloudinary storage, I'd be so appreciative! I am very confused on the multer/cloudinar setup in the backend.

MyApp: [https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/ChiomaGrace/AngularApp](https://stackblitz.com/%7E/github.com/ChiomaGrace/AngularApp)

[image: Screenshot of browser console logs]

Comment: The link to the code you shared doesn't work

Comment: Apologies! Here it is: https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/ChiomaGrace/AngularApp